Calculating number of trees of $n$ vertices by counting edges that can be removed from $K_n$.
Let $K_4$ be the complete graph of $4$ vertices. $K_4$ has $6$ edges. Assume vertices are labeled.
Any tree of $4$ vertices can be formed by removing three edges from $K_4$. There are $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to select three edges out of the six, which gives $20$ possible selections. This should entail $20$ trees of $4$ vertices can be formed by removing edges from $K_4$. But the bijection between Prufer sequences and trees entails there are $4^{2} = 16$ trees of four vertices.
The reasoning behind the formation of trees via removal of edges from a $K_n$ must be wrong. But where is the error?

While removing arbitrary three edges you should take care that the remaining graph is connected. So $ 4$ possibilities are forbidden.

I chose $K_4$ because one cannot remove three edges and disconnect it. Or am I missing something?

You can. Choose one vertex and remove three edges connecting it with other three vertices.

Thanks and god bless you.

And is there some generalization on the number of "forbidden" edges for a $K_n$?
